# Meaning of "primers IL-2" in a scientific article

Tags: immunology, terminology, pcr, immune-system, primer

[From an article](http://jpet.aspetjournals.org/content/305/1/70) ("Amelioration of Experimental Autoimmune Encephalomyelitis in Lewis Rats by FTY720 Treatment", 2003):

> We performed PCR amplification in a 100-μl reaction mixture containing 200 μM of each of the regular dNTPs, 10 pmol of each primer, and 2.5 U of TaqDNA polymerase (TaKaRa) using **primers IL-2** (300 base pairs; bp), 5′-CAGCTGTTGCT GGACTTACAGG-3′ and 5′-CACAGTTGATGGCTCATCATCG-3′; IL-6 (294 bp), 5′-GACTTCACAGAGGATACCC-3′ and 5′-TAAGTTGTTCTTCACAAACTCC-3′; INF-γ (310 bp), 5′-GGATATCTGGAGGAACTGGCAAAAG-3′ and 5′-GCTAGATT CTGGTGACAGCTGGTG-3′; β-actin (461 bp) 5′-CATCGTGGGCCGCTCTAGGCA-3′ and 5′-CCGGCCAGCCAAGTCCAGACGC-3′.

I'm not completely sure: do they mean that the primers are "specific to the IL-2 gene"?

Do they mean "5′-CAGCTGTTGCT GGACTTACAGG-3′ and 5′-CACAGTTGATGGCTCATCATCG-3′ are primers that are specific to the IL-2 gene"?

Comment: Looks like they're missing a semi-colon so yes, primers; IL-2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, yes, those primers are supposed to be specific for the IL-2 gene. The way they would be used would be on mRNA, not DNA, so you could use them to quantify the level of IL-2 transcription. However, there seems to be some glitch in there, because while the first sequence (5′-CAGCTGTTGCT GGACTTACAGG-3′) matches [rat IL-2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nucleotide/16758691?report=genbank&log$=nuclalign&blast_rank=1&RID=D26ZT24501N) mRNA starting at 120 in the sequence,  the second one (CACAGTTGATGGCTCATCATCG) does not match any IL-2; a BLAST search only turns up random and irrelevant matches.

This may be an error in the paper (copying and pasting the wrong primer, which is extremely common, unfortunately); it may have been an error in design (someone used the wrong primer and got lucky results that seemed to match what they expect); or I may be doing something wrong, which I'm not going to try to troubleshoot any more than this.

(**Edit**, as @VonBeche points out in comments the reverse primer is almost a match at 398, with a one-nucleotide mismatch that screwed up my search -- possibly allelic variant, but equally possibly a mistake)

Comment: The reverse primer starts at 398. Nice trick for blasting specific sequences like this: set the species to rat (or whatever you need). Especially with short you'll find too much uselessness otherwise.

Comment: Annoyingly it's not a perfect match (A/C at 9) so my grep on the sequence didn't find it.

Comment: @iayork, That's why we have BLAT ; )